# Capturing the delete/backspace keys in SproutCore

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-events, sproutcore

I have a SproutCore Pane - a PalettePane, specifically - which includes a form tied to an object elsewhere on the screen. The Pane is causing trouble with the object deletion interaction. The way I want it to work is:

- If a text input field is in focus, the backspace/delete keys should apply to those fields (i.e. editing the text)
- If no text input field has focus, the backspace/delete keys should delete the selected object related to the form. (The pane appears when the user has selected an object, so if the pane exists there's a selected object.)

So far, I get one of these behaviors or the other, never both. If I set `acceptsKeyPane: YES` in the Pane, I get the backspace/delete keys applying to the text fields, but no deleting of selected objects when the text fields don't have focus. If I use `acceptsKeyPane: NO`, when I'm editing a text field and hit backspace, it deletes the object I was trying to edit.

To add insult to injury, in Firefox with `acceptsKeyPane: YES` the backspace key is caught by the browser and interpreted as a back-button click, which is going to be frustrating to the user.

I've looked at the `root_responder.js` code and it looks like SproutCore handles backspaces differently for Firefox, but if I can handle them as described above the distinction between FF and other browsers should be moot.

ETA May 2011: Bear in mind when reading answers here that the SproutCore API for 1.5, 1.6 and beyond may not be the same as this.

Comment: Consider checking out the mailing list at sproutcore@googlegroups.com or the IRC channel at #sproutcore. (If I'm able to come up with a suggestion I'll answer it here as well.)

Comment: Thanks, Peter - I asked this question in the IRC channel and listened to the crickets chirping. The mailing list was only started yesterday, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how we finally wound up doing it:

- When the pane was created, we called `becomeFirstResponder()` on it.
- We added `acceptsFirstResponder: YES` to its view definition.
- Then we added to the view definition:

```
    keyDown: function(evt) {
      return this.interpretKeyEvents(evt) ? YES : NO;
    },

    deleteBackward: function() {
      this.get('objectToEdit').destroy();
      return YES;
    },

    deleteForward: function() {
      this.get('objectToEdit').destroy();
      return YES;
    }
```

...and that did the trick.